# How does one determine the height of a data point using the ASP.Net charting controls?

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I have a stacked column chart like so:

[image]

I'm using a text annotation to display the $2495 in the rightmost stacked column. I've determined the proper y position experimentally - obviously that won't work for dynamically generated content.

Does anyone know how I can determine the height of the data points which compose the column? I presumed it would be something like:

```
Chart1.Series[0][0].Height + Chart1.Series[1][0].Height + Chart1.Series[3][0].Height + Chart1.Series[4][0].Height
```

But, alas, it is apparently not that simple. Any thoughts or insight would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link

http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/WebChart2005/Custom_Drawing_Using_the_Paint_Event.html

See the examples at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks...the ultimate answer I needed I posted below, but this started me on the path to it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's all much simpler than I thought...the annotations use *chart* coordinates. This means that all you have to do is sum the actual *values* and use that as a y coordinate. I ended up doing this to calculate the heights of the respective series:

```
private int CalculateHeight(int i, ChartGraphics graphics)
{
    var height = 0.0;

    // find the respective heights of series i, add them together
    for (var x = 0; x < this.Chart1.Series.Count(); x++)
    {
        height += this.Chart1.Series[x].Points[i].YValues[0]; 
    }

    return (int)height;
}
```

I then call that function like so:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.Series[0].Points.Count(); i++ )
        {
            var height = this.CalculateHeight(i, e.ChartGraphics);

            this.Chart1.Annotations[i].Y = height + verticalPadding;
        }
```

Much simpler than I thought.